# Is there a service that offers a VPN, or VPN-like service that terminates on the cellular network?

Tags: web-services, internet, vpn

I'm looking for a service that I can use to route outgoing internet requests through the cell network, i.e. the request will appear to originate from a cell IP.

Currently I'm using ngrok and an old phone, but I'm looking to scale up, as this system is getting overloaded. Rather than managing more hardware I'm wondering if this is offered as a service anywhere?